# Rails 7 and AWS Aurora (MySQL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, amazon-aurora

I have a Rails 7 application, using an AWS RDS instance. Unfortunately, I a MySQL RDS is cannot be automatically scaled, so I am thinking about moving to Aurora, with MySQL.

I am however not sure how to prepare my Rails 7 application for the switch, and primarily have a couple of questions:

1. Do I still use the mysql gem?
2. What changes do I need to make to ActiveStorage, to address the Aurora architecture, which is a minimum of two instances, one for reading and one for writing?